# Is CocoaPods Used in Production?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, production

I am not entirely sure if this is the appropriate place to ask this question, but given that CocoaPods is a third-party Xcode plugin not made by Apple is CocoaPods ever used in the professional computer science industry? I know several apps made by fellow individual developers that utilize CocoaPods because it's one less headache (same reason I like the idea), but is it even worth getting familiar with if companies you are interested in working at that make iOS apps don't even use it? Or do companies not care and leave it entirely up to the developer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cocoapods is just a tool to find, clone, build, and link against app dependancies. Ultimately, it just creates an .xcworkspace where all of the dependancies are linked to your main app. While Cocoapods isn't a first-party tool, it's only job is to create and configure an .xcworkspace, which is a first party tool. Everything Cocoapods does could be done manually using Xcode.

It's also worth mentioning [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) as another alternative for dependency management. Carthage simple clones and builds frameworks, it leaves it up to you to drag them into your .xcodeproj and link them. This is a less intrusive approach in that it doesn't create or require an xcworkspace.

EDIT: To address your specific question, yes, both Cocoapods and Carthage have widespread, almost ubiquitous use in the professional world. These tools have become the defacto standard for managing dependancies in Xcode. While you can get by without them, doing this all manually is error prone and wastes time when we have established conventions.

While I can't speak to closed source software such as Google's apps, the fact that they offer pods is a clear indicator that they expect you as a developer to use them. You don't see any instructions from Google on how to setup/build their frameworks from a git submodule now do you?

Comment: +1 for thoroughness and I will definitely check out Carthage. The thing I like about CocoaPods is that you can include a framework as a dependency and it will recompile the framework if it has changed and is in your workspace, but I suppose companies would lean more towards Carthage because its less intrusive as you said?

Comment: Cocoapods will only pull in new changes for a framework if you run `pod install`. The same is true for Carthage but with `carthage update`. The main difference is Cocoapods sets up the linkage, with carthage you have to drag it in and link it. I can't think of a way where this would affect anyone beyond the developer. Try them both and use whichever one you like more.

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that Google like CocoaPods so much. Watch this video in Route85 series about it: https://youtu.be/iEAjvNRdZa0?t=2m56s 
.
"We like it so much that Google is now making it the official way we distribute a growing number of our libraries to the world, including AdMob, Google Sign-in, and Google Analytics."

Answer (score 1):

CocoaPods is a dependency manager for Objective-C and Swift. Many developers add their libraries to CocoaPods. By using it, you're enabling your projects to scale in a reliable way.

You don't have to use CocoaPods. You could always manually add a library to your project, but CocoaPods has become a standard in the professional iOS development industry for its elegance and dependability. CocoaPods is sponsored by big companies, like Capital One. Stripe uses it (http://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios). So does Twitter (http://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ios/getting-started).

CocoaPods is not very hard to learn at all if you want to get started in it. Yes, it seems scary because it creates an `xcworkspace`, but it only  takes about two minutes to first start using it. And for the record – you're simply working on your project by opening up your `xcworkspace` instead of `xcodeproj`. Nothing too frightening ;)

The official getting started guide: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html

A helpful tutorial that walks you through it: https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Comment: +1 for directly answering my question. So, that's a yes it is used in the professional field? Could you cite a source that states a company like Google has its developers use CocoaPods? I mean I know Google offers CocoaPods for things like Drive, but do their developers use it?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Yup, it's for sure used in the professional field. CocoaPods is sponsored by big companies, like Capital One. Stripe uses it (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios). So does Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ios/getting-started). As a side note, CocoaPods has been around for a lot longer than Carthage.

Comment: Awesome. That's what I needed to hear! Thanks

Comment: can you edit your answer to include the portion with the citation as well?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Sure thing